# Error when using label 'wait' in NASM macro

Tags: assembly, macros, nasm

I am using a macro in NASM to define some repetitive functions. I use the following code:

```
; System call numbers
%define SYS_fork    1
%define SYS_exit    2
%define SYS_wait    3

; define the macro
%macro SYSCALL 1
global %1
%1:
  mov eax, SYS_%1
  int 64 ; 64 is system call
  ret
%endmacro

; call the macro to setup the functions
SYSCALL fork
SYSCALL exit
SYSCALL wait
```

This works fine, except for the last call to create a macro with the name `wait`. It gives me the error:

```
error: parser: instruction expected
```

Is `wait` a reserved word in nasm? If so is there a way to still define a function called `wait`?

Comment: Yes to both questions. The [NASM manual](http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc3.html) says _An identifier may also be prefixed with a $ to indicate that it is intended to be read as an identifier and not a reserved word_ . So on your line in your macro that says `%1:` change it to `$%1:`

Comment: @MichaelPetch Thx alot, that was what i was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `WAIT` and `FWAIT` are part of the x86_64 instruction set. I'm sure you've tried changing the name in your code (Block? HoldUp?) and the error is removed so that would also fix the issue.